# How to connect specific attributes over polar coordinates in R?

Tags: polar-coordinates

I have highlighted specific activities (feeding,resting and sleeping) from the dataset in my plot. Now I want to connect these highlighted points in sequence over my polar coordinates.

Here's my dataset:

```
Activity  Latitude  Longitude
Feeding   21.09542  71.06014
Resting   21.09564  71.06064
Sleeping  21.09619  71.06128
Walking   21.09636  71.06242
Walking   21.09667  71.06564
Resting   21.09483  71.06619
```

Can you help me out in this?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. Could you reformulate your question? Please make sure to provide a reproductible dataset `set.seed(1);mydf=data.frame(Activity=sample(c("Walking","Feeding","Resting","Sleeping"),100,T),Latitude=rnorm(100,21,0.5),Longitude=rnorm(100,71,0.5))`  as well as your code and the packages you are using. It makes it easier to help you out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I am starting from scratch: My original answerwas much too bulky and inflexible.

Just add the following to get Paths for each Activity without filtering.

```
+ geom_path(aes(colour=ACTIVITY,x=Latitude,y=Longitude))
```

[image]

If you want to plot only selected Activities:

```
+ geom_path(data=Data[Data$ACTIVITY %in% c("Sleeping","Resting"),],aes(colour=ACTIVITY,x=Latitude,y=Longitude))
```

[image]

The selected Activities are to be listed in the `c(...)` vector with each name quoted.

UPDATE: OP clarified that he wants to connect any stationary point, this achieved by running the following:

```
+ geom_path(data=Data[Data$ACTIVITY!="Walking",],colour="red",aes(x=Latitude,y=Longitude))
```

Note that the colour=ACTIVITY is removed from the aesthetics and we consider all stationary points (!="Walking") to draw the path.

Code combining the two answers:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf=data.frame(Activity=sample(c("Walking","Walking","Walking","Walking","Walking","Resting","Feeding","Sleeping"),20,T),Latitude=rnorm(20,21,0.5),Longitude=rnorm(20,71,0.5))
mydf$Order=1:nrow(mydf)

# Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=mydf)+
geom_point(aes(x=Latitude,y=Longitude,colour=Activity),size=5)+
geom_path(aes(x=Latitude,y=Longitude),size=1.2)+
geom_text(aes(x=Latitude,y=Longitude,label=Order))+
geom_path(data=mydf[mydf$Activity!="Walking",],colour="red",aes(x=Latitude,y=Longitude)) +
coord_polar(theta="y")
```

[image]

Comment: Can you see Clement answer? After what Clement has done,  I want to plot(connect) resting, feeding and sleeping points over the same plot as similar to the answer given by Clement.

Comment: I added another try but looking at your figure it seems you want them to be connected without polar coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

```
# Example dataframe    
set.seed(1)
mydf=data.frame(Activity=sample(c("Walking","Feeding","Resting","Sleeping"),20,T),Latitude=rnorm(20,21,0.5),Longitude=rnorm(20,71,0.5))
mydf$Order=1:nrow(mydf)
```

If you want to connect the points in order regardless of the activity, do the following (for clarity, I added the variable mydf$Order to label the points).

```
# Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=mydf)+
  geom_point(aes(x=Latitude,y=Longitude,colour=Activity))+
  geom_path(aes(x=Latitude,y=Longitude))+
  geom_text(aes(x=Latitude,y=Longitude,label=Order))+
  coord_polar(theta="y")
```

[image]

If you want to connect points according to activities, consider CMichael's answer.

Comment: nice example data Generator!

Comment: Its not fully correct. What I have done is:

1. I have your solution. (i.e., I have plot the same as you did in 1st step)

2. Now I want to plot(connect) resting, feeding and sleeping points over the same plot as similar to the first step. Can you help me in this 2nd part